# Creating User-Subscribed Content Areas in Joomla 1.6

Tags: php, user-controls, joomla, joomla1.6

In my Joomla project, I need a user registration module, which has 3 kind of memberships: Gold, Silver and Bronze.

In each member level, they can see some part of the website, the gold member can see all the things and Silver have a part of them and the Bronze level have only few parts to see.

Is there a good Joomla extension that I can use for this purpose? I tried to find in extensions.joomla.org but couldn't find a right one.

I am using Joomla 1.6 if anyone knows a good plugin for that, please help me or tell me how can I do it with the default user login and registration system which is bundled with Joomla 1.6. I found some similar extensions like JUGA and K2, but they're not compatible with Joomla 1.6

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account Expiration Control (AEC) is what you seek. It comes in 1.6 native and integrates well with the built in ACL. Plus it has all kinds of built in payment options making it a one stop shop for paid content/membership sites.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/10723

Comment: Hi Brent, thanks a lot for your help, this is exactly what I was looking for. You saved the day :)